# Central Administration cannot be found

Tags: 2013, central-administration

When I select CA , It says "The webpage cannot be found". I also did configuration with sp wizard and it failed.What should I do?

Comment: Look in Internet Information Services, see if the websites and application pools are running.

Comment: Is this a new farm? Have you ever been able to access CA? How much RAM does this machine have (guest memory if this is a virtual machine)?

Comment: No it's not new. I guess it's because of the db.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open up IIS Manager
1. Start > Type INETMGR in the search textbox and run it.
2. When IIS Manager opens click the server name in the "Connections" panel.
3. Expand the "Sites" node.
4. Select "Central Administration" and click "Browse Web Site" in the "Actions" panel.

Note the URL and you should be able to access "Central Administration" directly from your browser.

Lets assume that you are doing this on the server that is hosting Central Admin.

Answer (score 4):

1. Click the start button and start to type Central Administration. When *SharePoint 2013 Central Administration* shows - click on it, and the browser should start and you should be able to see Central Administration. If CA still doesn't work...
2. Go to Interent Information Service (IIS) Manager and see that the web site is running and that the application pool is started. If CA still doesn't work...
3. Go to the services and see if SharePoint 2013 Administration is started. If CA still doesn't work...
4. Check that SQL Server is running and that SharePoint system databases are running. If CA still doesn't work...
5. Check that you have sufficient memory and disk available on your virtual/non-virtual machine.

Comment: Everythings fine; the memory, the services, the ca are running. Now it says "Sorry, something went wrong"

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you run configuration wizard again. Don't disconnect from the server or don't do any name modification, leave everything as it is and just press next. The sharepoint will start working again.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent Worked for me with this step

I suggest you run configuration wizard again. Don't disconnect from the server or don't do any name modification, leave everything as it is and just press next. The sharepoint will start working again.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the app pool is running and the CA site is up in IIS.
OR
Replace the url with local host for CA, if it works then problem may be with the host file. map the server name and domain to local host ip 127.0.0.1

Host file located at:

C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\Etc

Answer (score -2):

For me was lack of space on C:
then ran Wizard as administrator
and CA is back again